# Highlight cells based on date and other conditions

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, highlight

I am trying to code in VBA a highlighting function based on certain conditions. I can easily do this via conditional formatting, but I have noticed that if a user cuts/pastes (other than special)/deletes rows/etc. then the conditional formatting ranges are modified. I want the conditional formatting ranges to stay fixed rather than mapped to the actual cells. If anyone knows how to do that, or protect the conditional formatting but still allow data manipulation, then this code would be unnecessary.

I have found two different codes that I have been trying but since I'm new to VBA, I'm not very good at it and run into problems. I don't know how to use the Isblank or Isempty feature for one.

I need to highlight dates that are earlier than 30 days from now (including dates passed) in red. I need to highlight dates that are earlier than 60 days from now but more than 30 in yellow. Cells without data and cells beyond 60 days out must remain unhighlighted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim icolor As Integer

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3:T65")) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target

            Case Is <= Date + 60

                icolor = 6

            Case Is <= Date + 30

                icolor = 3

            Case IsEmpty()

                icolor = 2

        End Select


        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor

    End If

End Sub
```

Other option:

```
Sub Highlight()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("C3:T65")
        If cell.Value <= Date + 60 And cell.Value > Date + 30 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

        ElseIf cell.Value <= Date + 30 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        ElseIf cell.Value IsEmpty() Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 2

        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your codes are almost there. The following combination of the two should do the job:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If Intersect(Target, Range("C3:T65")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In Target
        icolor = 0
        Select Case cell
            Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
            Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 6
            Case "": icolor = 2
        End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Compile Error: "Case without Select Case" with "Case cell" highlighted.

Do I insert a "Do Select" somewhere?

Comment: I inserted "Select" before "Case cell" and it worked. However, now I have a problem:

If I select a cell and hit "Backspace" then the cell turns yellow despite it being empty. Also, the `Case Is <= Date + 60` is overriding the `Case Is <= Date + 30`. Any idea on how to make the yellow one inclusive from > Date + 30 to <= Date + 60?

Comment: I figured it out. I re-arranged the Case lines in reverse order and it fixed it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user2214690: sorry the missing `Select`- i edited the code and also reversed the order. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 0):

Check the cell is null using VBNullString:

```
ElseIf cell.Value = vbNullString Then
```

Comment: Is this for the second coding I listed above in place of `ElseIf cell.Value IsEmpty() Then`?

Comment: Indeed. You were almost there but you used a spreadsheet formula in the condition

Comment: I manipulated Peter Albert's code above and it worked well.

I just tried using your change and the script comes back with no errors but then it fails to highlight correctly. A lot of random cells were highlighted red. I tried to re-arrange the ElseIf and If code to see if it would do anything, but then it brings up new highlighting issues.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No problem. If you need to check for blank cells or strings in the future, at least you know now!