# How to use VBA to highlight cells if 30 days past?

Tags: excel, vba

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670553/highlight-cells-based-on-date-and-other-conditions) which was a good starting point, but I'm in an INDIRECT situation that I can't keep conditional formatting with the sheet because the table/sheet is repeatedly deleted/updated.

Table has a column to have 30 day old+ highlighted red.

The conditional formatting would be `=J2<TODAY()-30`,  (anything 30 days or more would be red)

I tried the code, and it highlighted cells, but I have to click in + enter to activate.

I'm trying to get it as a module to call from a user button but spent the past few days trying and I can't figure it out

The INDIRECT feature would be sheet name: owssvr

`Range: J2:J1000`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim icolor As Integer
Dim cell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each cell In Target
    icolor = 0
    Select Case cell
        Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
    End Select
    If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
Next cell
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you can do is have a cell that you use vba to put the sheet name in (when the changes are made). Then link the conditional formatting to use that cell value as the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't a VBA fix but a workaround.

Name Range the column, "PaintRed" or etc, conditional format

Apply to "PaintRed"

Comment: Surely you can do better than that. You wouldn't wanna get an answer in this format. Try to describe in more detail what you exactly did, and accept your answer since it is a great idea, so someone else with a similar issue can easily understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's time to play dirty...

...by forcing an update:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim icolor As Integer
Dim cell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each cell In Target
    icolor = 0
    Select Case cell
        Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
    End Select
    If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor

    ''' Force update here (Note: This might not be ideal and change to suit your needs.)'''
    cell.Dirty

Next cell

End Sub
```